# Simplest function sufficient to categorize a square

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

**Background** Let $p_i=(x_i,y_i)$ with $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ define four (possibly repeating) points in the plane. Let $f(a,b,c)$ be any function with the property that

$$f(a,b,c)=f(a,c,b)=f(b,a,c)=f(b,c,a)=f(c,a,b)=f(c,b,a)$$

That is, the output of $f$ is independent on any permutations of the inputs. Finally, define

$$S_1=f(d(p_1,p_2),d(p_1,p_3),d(p_1,p_4))$$

where $d(a,b)$ is the standard Euclidean distance (although this could really be any metric). In a similar manner, define $S_2,S_3,$ and $S_4$. We say that a function $f$ categorizes a square if

$$S_1=S_2=S_3=S_4\Leftrightarrow \text{The points }p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\text{ define a square}$$

Obviously, the $\Leftarrow$ implication is self-evident (at least if one considers four identical points a square). This leaves the question of what functions $f$ imply that the points $p$ form a square?

**Question:** What is the simplest such function $f$ which categorizes a square? In this question, 'simple' can be taken to mean: cleanest, neatest, easiest to compute, etc.

**Work so far:** The obvious choice for $f$ is

$$f(a,b,c)=a+b+c$$

By almost any definition, this is probably the simplest function which could possibly categorize a square (this is opposed to constant $f$ which definitely does not categorize the square). However, I could not prove that this function works although I can show it for the following function:

$$f(a,b,c)=\left(\frac{\max\{a,b,c\}}{\sqrt{2}}-\min\{a,b,c\}\right)^2+\left(a+b+c-\max\{a,b,c\}-2\min\{a,b,c\}\right)^2+\min\{a,b,c\}$$

This function evaluates to $\min\{a,b,c\}$ if the two shorter distances are equal and the longest distance is equal to the shorter distances after being stretched by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

To prove this function categorizes a square, it is sufficient to prove cases depending on how many of the lengths amongst the four points equal the absolute minimum length (in a square, its four of the lengths). Since $\binom{4}{2}=6$, one simply has to check the cases:

$$\text{There is $1$ unique minimum distance among $6$ lengths}$$

$$\text{There are $2$ equal minimum distances among $6$ lengths}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\text{There are $5$ equal minimum distances among $6$ lengths}$$

(the case where all the distance are equal is impossible). After going through the logic, one can show that in all cases but the case with $4$ equal minimum distances that $S_i\neq S_j$ for some $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then in this case, you can show that this corresponds to a square.

Comment: Suppose $f$ is any function of the form $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \alpha + (\beta,\beta,\beta) \cdot x$. Then plug in the situation of a rectangle with side lengths $A$ and $B$. If you are getting all the $S_i$ equal without needing $A=B$ you are seeing that $f$ must either/both have some nonpolynomial pieces and/or something of degree above $1$ like what you already is using both quadratic pieces and nonpolynomial pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

If $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are the vertices of a (possibly degenerate) rectangle, then
$$
S_1=S_2=S_3=S_4
$$
holds, regardless of the choice of the symmetric function $f(a,b,c)$.

In what follows, let $f(a,b,c)=a+b+c$.

**Claim:**$\;$If $S_1=S_2=S_3=S_4$, then $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are the vertices of a (possibly degenerate) rectangle.

**Proof:**

Assume $S_1=S_2=S_3=S_4=s$.

If $s=0$, then $p_1=p_2=p_3=p_4$, in which case, $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are the vertices of a degenerate rectangle.

Next assume $s > 0$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume $s=1$.

For $1\le i < j\le 4$, let $d_{ij}=d(p_i,p_j)$

After appropriate re-indexing we have $6$ cases, exactly one of which must hold . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;p_1=p_2=p_3,\,p_3\ne p_4$.

Then from $S_1=S_2=S_3=1$ we get $d_{14}=d_{24}=d_{34}=1$, but then $S_4=3$, contradiction.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;p_1=p_2,\,p_3=p_4,\,p_1\ne p_3$.

Then it's immediate that $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are the vertices of a degenerate rectangle.

**Case $(3)$:**$\;p_1=p_2,\,p_2\ne p_3,\,p_2\ne p_4,\,p_3\ne p_4$.

Then we get
$$
2
=
2S_1
=
2d_{13}+2d_{14}
 <
(2d_{13}+d_{34})+(2d_{14}+d_{34})
=
S_3+S_4
=
2
$$
contradiction.

**Case $(4)$:**$\;p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are distinct, but collinear.

Without loss of generality, assume $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are consecutive points on the line segment with endpoints $p_1,p_4$.

Then we get
$$
S_1
=
3d_{12}+2d_{23}+d_{34}
 >
d_{12}+2d_{23}+d_{34}
=
S_2
$$
contradiction.

**Case $(5)$:**$\;p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are distinct, and $p_4\in T$, where $T$ is a non-degenerate closed triangular region with vertices $p_1,p_2,p_3$.

Without loss of generality, assume $d_{23}=\max(d_{12},d_{13},d_{23})$.

It follows that $d_{14} < d_{23}$.

Now we have
\begin{align*}
3
&=\,
S_1+S_2+S_3
\\[4pt]
&=\,
2(d_{12}+d_{13}+d_{23})+(d_{14}+d_{24}+d_{34})
\\[4pt]
&=\,
2(d_{12}+d_{13}+d_{23})+S_4
\\[4pt]
&=\,
2(d_{12}+d_{13}+d_{23})+1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $d_{12}+d_{13}+d_{23}=1$.

But then we get
$$
1
=
S_1
=
d_{12}+d_{13}+d_{14}
 < 
d_{12}+d_{13}+d_{23}
=
1
$$
contradiction.

**Case $(6)$:**$\;p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are consecutive vertices of a convex quadrilateral, $Q$ say.

From $S_1=S_3$ we get 
$$
d_{14}+d_{12}=d_{23}+d_{34}\qquad(\text{eq}1)
$$
and from $S_2=S_4$ we get 
$$
d_{12}+d_{23}=d_{34}+d_{14}\qquad(\text{eq}2)
$$
Subtracting $(\text{eq}2)$ from $(\text{eq}1)$ yields
$$
d_{14}-d_{23}=d_{23}-d_{14}
$$
hence $d_{14}=d_{23}=x$, say.

Then $(\text{eq}1)$ becomes
$$
x+d_{12}=x+d_{34}
$$
hence $d_{12}=d_{34}=y$, say.

Thus the opposite sides of $Q$ have equal lengths, so $Q$ is a parallelogram.

Then from $S_1=S_2$ we get 
$$
x+y+d_{13}=y+x+d_{24}
$$
hence $d_{13}=d_{24}$, so the diagonals of $Q$ have equal lengths.

It follows that $Q$ is a rectangle.

This completes the proof.